# JavaScript addEventListener only to main container and second child elements

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

How can I add an event to only the main container and to it's second child elements? In this case, it's `id="container"` and all `class="secondChild"`

What I current do add a listener to all elements inside the `div`

```
ele = document.getElementById('container');
ele.addEventListener('mousedown',myFunction)

<div class="main" id="container">
    <div class="firstChild">
        <div class="secondChild">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="innerOne">This is Element 1</div>
                <div class="innerTwo">This is Element 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondChild">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="innerOne">This is Element 3</div>
                <div class="innerTwo">This is Element 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondChild">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="innerOne">This is Element 5</div>
                <div class="innerTwo">This is Element 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is called Event Delegation and is very common to do. Does this answer your question? [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: The same event listener for all of them?

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía Yes. Same event for all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can go with Event Delegation:

From: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

> Event delegation makes use of two often overlooked features of
> JavaScript events: event bubbling and the target element. When an
> event is triggered on an element, for example a mouse click on a
> button, the same event is also triggered on all of that element’s
> ancestors. This process is known as event bubbling; the event bubbles
> up from the originating element to the top of the DOM tree. The target
> element of any event is the originating element, the button in our
> example, and is stored in a property of the event object. Using event
> delegation it’s possible to add an event handler to an element, wait
> for an event to bubble up from a child element and easily determine
> from which element the event originated.

So you attach the listener to `#container` (you can attach it any ancestor), and the check for the event's target class (or whatever other property you want)

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('event-name', ev => {

    switch(ev.target.className) {
        case 'inner':
        case 'innerOne':
        case 'innerTwo':
            // do something?
            break;
    }

});
```

(or maybe change the class to `secondChild`, I actually didn't quite get what element's were you trying to attach handlers to. Also sorry for my english)